# How to implement identity server 3 localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization, oauth-2.0, identityserver3, identityserver4

I have an identityserver3 as a separate server for authenticating multiple client.

I want to localize it and i used [IdentityServer3.Contrib.Localization](https://github.com/johnkors/IdentityServer3.Contrib.Localization) for that, now i know that this is it's usage:

```
  var options = new LocaleOptions { Locale = "nb-NO" };
  var localizationService = new GlobalizedLocalizationService(options);
```

In IdentityServer startUp class, i have a services factory like:

```
 idServerServiceFactory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationDbContext>());
            idServerServiceFactory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, UserService>();
            idServerServiceFactory.Register(new Registration<UserManager>());
            idServerServiceFactory.Register(new Registration<UserStore>());
```

And in options:

```
    var options = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                Factory = idServerServiceFactory,
                SiteName = .....
```

I try to register the localization service to the identityserver servicesFactory but it didn't works correctly also i didn't find and samples on how to use it, can any one help in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/localization.html) you need to register your `ILocalizationService`, like so:

```
factory.LocalizationService = 
   new Registration<ILocalizationService>(localizationService);
```

I don't see that in your example code.

If you already have that you might want to explain how it isn't working and expand on your code samples.

Comment: i actually open SO to post the answer but you got it, thanks :)